# Problems with the Date 31-12-9999 in java

Tags: java

My program needs to represent this date as a java.sql.date object , but it seems that when I create a new date (using the calendar) and set it to '9999-12-31' and finally convert this java.util.date object to a java.sql.date object, this date is converted to something like '000-01-31'.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(9999, 12, 31);
infinityDate = new java.sql.Date(normalizeDate(calendar.getTime()).getTime());
```

infinityDate should be 31-12-9999
but when my code reaches here :

```
if(otherDate.equals(infinityDate))
{// Do stuff}
```

It never goes into the if condition as the infinityDate has for some reason been changed to 31-01-000, even though otherDate is infact '31-12-9999'.

The fact that otherDate is 31-12-9999 tells me that java can represent this dates , but for some reason , when I construct it using a calendar it changes the date. (otherDate comes from a jdbc statement which fetches data from a database)

This reference date '31-12-9999' has been fixed by some client , so it cannot be changed and my program has to be able to compare some incoming date values with this.
Does anyone know why this is happening , I realize that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem may be a problem for dates after year 9999 , but I should be safe by a day.

EDIT : The Normalize date method only  "normalizes the given date to midnight of that day"

```
    private static java.util.Date normalizeDate(java.util.Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    date = calendar.getTime();

    return date;
}
```

But , this issue was appearing before I was normalizing the date , I normalized it in an attempt to fix this.

Comment: What does the normalizeDate function do?

Comment: I would advise against using a "marker" date like this.  It's a fragile way to represent unrelated logic.

Comment: @Ramhound As I indicated , its not by my choice , this is part of a requirement spec that I received.

Comment: @angryInsomniac - I missed that information. Are you 100% sure the database technolgy can support the date values your forced to use?  You have not given us enough information.  You might consider informing your client their reference date has several problems.

Comment: @Ramhound How have I not given enough information ?
In any case , the query has been resolved ! and yes , I am sure that the database can support the date in question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Months are zero indexed.  Use `11` for December, not `12`.  This is why you are rolling over the year.

Comment: Ok , that fixed it ! Thanks !
But why would months be 0 indexed ? That's so counter-intuitive !

Comment: Don't use 11, use Calendar.DECEMBER

Comment: There are two stupidities, among others in this class: (a) months are zero-indexed while the day of the month isn't; (b) if you enter an invalid value, the class silently exhibits unexpected behaviour rather than throwing an exception. Calendar is just a slightly duffly designed class. Don't worry about it unduly, but don't emulate this behaviour in your own code...!

Answer (score 5):

Calendar.MONTH is zero-based. The call

```
calendar.set(9999, 12, 31);
```

sets the date to "the 31st day in the 13th month of the year 9999", which is then implicitly converted to the 1st month of the year 10000. It would result in an exception if you first called

```
calendar.setLenient(false);
```

Comment: Ok , that fixed it ! Thanks !
But why would months be 0 indexed ? That's so counter-intuitive !

Comment: @angryInsomniac: I think it's inherited from the C libraries: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/

Answer (score 0):

Check hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds that are held into these 2 date objects. I believe they are different.

If your want to compare the date (year, month, day) only you should probably create your custom `Comparator` and use it.

Comment: I just edited the question with what the NormalizeDate() method does. Its basic function is to remove all time related data from these dates.